# Is there an event raised when objects are allocated to the Large Object Heap, C#?

Tags: c#, memory-management

I'd like to have my program (say in a memory watching mode) tell me when it's allocating something onto the Large Object Heap.  This way I can maybe tune areas that should not be using the LOH.

Is there an event raised when objects are allocated to the Large Object Heap?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Garbage Collection Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162.aspx) under [CLR ETW Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264810.aspx):

You'll be most interested in `GCAllocationTick_V2 Event` and `GCStart_V1 Event`.

Answer (score 0):

An object of size >= 85000 bytes is allocated on LOH. As far as I am aware, no event is raised unless you want to provide custom implementation of Memory Allocation to CLR. You however can use SOS (Son of Strike) debugging extension to analyze heap.